# Opening another excel file and copy the "specific" filtered columns to the current active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

Im trying to open another workbook with a filtered columns but every time I run the macro, it only copies 1 visible cell only to my active workbook.

here's the code that I use

```
Sub SelectAfile()
'Select a file Macro
    Dim FileLocation As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, wsPaste As Worksheet, curr_lrow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ImportWorkbook As Workbook, wsImport As Worksheet
    
    'Open File
    FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileLocation = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a file.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook         'Copy
    Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets(1)  'Paste
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)
    Set wsImport = ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
    LastRow = wsImport.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 
    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A 
    curr_lrow = wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'safer than .End(xlDown)...
    
    CopyValues wsImport.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsPaste.Range("A" & curr_lrow)
    CopyValues wsImport.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsPaste.Range("b" & curr_lrow)
    CopyValues wsImport.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsPaste.Range("c" & curr_lrow)
    
End Sub

Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range) 'Continuation from SelectAfile
    With rngFrom
        rngTo.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried some other codes like looping through each visible cells but it takes too long when the data is big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a breakpoint in your CopyValues function and examine `rngFrom.Address` you will notice that it is a comma-separated "list" of ranges, not just a single range.
You need to deal with all of those Areas individually e.g. something like this might work for you

```
Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range) 'Continuation from SelectAfile
    Dim x As Variant
    With rngFrom
        For Each x In rngFrom.Areas
            rngTo.Resize(x.Rows.Count, x.Columns.Count).Value = x.Value
            **Set rngTo = rngTo.Offset(x.Rows.Count, 0)**
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code but every time the code pastes a value, it no longer searches the last used row after pasting the first visible area. 

`curr_lrow = wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

This doesn't seem work properly when the code loops through visible cells

Comment: to clarify my previous comment, the code keeps pasting the value to the "first" last row used by the first visible cell that were pasted. So if it copy first visible area on the opened workbook then paste **1,2,3,4,5** to range b4 (to active workbook) then it copies another value from the second visible area like 4,5,6 then the result will be 4,5,6,**4,5** on range b4 also.I think the problem is from the curr_lrow but I really don't know exactly why. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Mike - sorry I should have included a recalc of rngTo - I've amended my solution and highlighted the change with **